# Local Storage not working in filezilla and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Hej guys, I have problem with making Local Storage work in FileZilla and Safari, it works perfectly good in Google Chrome(as usually :D). It's not saving anything to local storage when button is pressed. Do you have some tips what should I add or change?? Thank you

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".logInAsAdmin").click(function(){
            var jStudent = {};
            jStudent.userSingUpNameLS = "Admin";
            jStudent.userLastNameLS= "Tivoli2016";
            console.log(jStudent);
            var sStudentsFromLocalStorage = localStorage.sajStudents;
            console.log(sStudentsFromLocalStorage);
            var aStudents = getDataFromLocalStorageAsObject();
            aStudents.push(jStudent);
                // console.log(aStudents);
                // convert the array into a string
                var sFinal = JSON.stringify(aStudents);
                console.log(sFinal);
                localStorage.sajStudents = sFinal;
                $(".myModal").modal('show');
                //e.preventDefault();
              });
    function getDataFromLocalStorageAsObject(){
      try{
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.sajStudents);
      }
      catch(e){
        return [];
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save in `localStorage` try like this

```
//Add
localStorage.setItem("Key", Value)

//Get
localStorage.getItem("Key");

//Remove
localStorage.removeItem("Key");
```